# How to get msgctxt in .po file with Django and pgetttext()

Tags: django, internationalization, gettext

I am writing a notification module for a booking app which has English and Spanish. It is supposed to be flexible enough to deal with any model and any status change (e.g. created, updated, cancelled etc).

The get_subject() function will prepare a 'subject' line for the notification using the related object's model name (e.g. Appointment) and the status verb. So we should get 'Appointment 123ABC modified' or 'Payment 789XYZ created' etc. I have it working translationwise all apart from allowing for the grammatical gender of words in Spanish. So 'Appointment 123ABC modified' would be 'Cit**a** 123ABC actualizad**a**' whereas say, 'Payment 123ABC modified' would be 'Pag**o** 123ABC actualizad**o**'.

I know the solution is to use pgettext(context, string) along with having the msgctxt in the .po file, but I just can't figure out how to get manage.py makemessages to add the msgctxt when it preps the .po file.

I have tried various ways of editing the .po directly but I am getting errors when running compilemessages (Execution of msgfmt failed: backend/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/django.po:3966: duplicate message definition...) and makemessages just overwrites my edits anyway.

I am not sure whether all I need is the right format for the po file or whether I need the right way of getting makemessages to work properly for my case. Any help would be much apprecited.

```
class Notification(Uuidable, Timestampable):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='notifications', verbose_name=_('notifications'), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    object_id = models.UUIDField(blank=True, null=True)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name=_('subject'))
    status_type = models.CharField(choices=NOTIFICACTION_STATUS_VERBS, max_length=256, verbose_name=_('status type'))
    details = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('details'))
    read_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('read at'))
    email_sent_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('email sent at'))
    pusher_sent_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('pusher sent at'))

    def generate_subject(self):
        class_name = self.content_object._meta.verbose_name
        context = str(class_name).lower()

        with translation.override(self.user.locale.split('-')[0]):
            class_name_translated = translation.gettext(class_name).capitalize()
            status_translated = translation.pgettext(context, str(self.status_type))

        subject = f'{class_name_translated} {self.content_object.display_id} {status_translated}'
        return subject

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject

    def get_email_template(self, template_type):
        return NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_TEMPLATES[self.content_object.__class__.__name__][self.status_type][template_type]

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.subject = _(self.generate_subject())
        return super(Notification, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message from `msgfmt` suggests that you are using the wrong syntax for the msgctxt in the `.po` file.  This is how it should look like:

```
msgctxt "abbreviated_weekday"
msgid "Sun"
msgstr ""
```

But you should extract the strings instead of manipulating the `.po` file. The solution is to generate a dummy source file that contains all the required calls to `pgettext()` so that the messages are properly extracted by `makemessages`.

In your code, the call to `pgettext()` has the message context in a variable instead of a string literal and such calls are, of course, ignored by `xgettext()`.